# MessageAnalyzer parse TLS on non-default 443 port

Tags: ssl, netmon

Message Analyzer seems to have no UI way to parse protocols on non-default ports. I have TLS server running on non standard port (not 443) and Message Analyzer won't parse captured as TLS.

Answer (score 0):

Quick workaround is to update TLS port from 443 to needed port number in C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Microsoft\MessageAnalyzer\OPNAndConfiguration\OPNs\CoreNetworking\TLS.opn

```
// http://www.iana.org/assignments/port-numbers
pattern Port = enum ushort
{
...
    HTTPS       = 443
```